# Why is "distro", rather than "distri", short for "distribution" in Linux world?

Tags: etymology, nouns, abbreviations, clipping

Why is *distro*, rather than *distri*, short for *distribution* in Linux world?

Comment: Well, it does, but only as the penultimate letter.

Comment: It's the phonetics. The last `i` in `distri` is phonetically an `o` hence `distro` being the phonetical prefix where as `distri` is simply the string prefix.

Comment: @DanD. that's an American pronunciation I take it?

Comment: @Chris H: I'm American, and that's not a pronunciation I recognize.

Comment: @PeterShor, it's certainly not a UK one, I think we need more details of Dan D.'s suggestion.

Comment: I vote 'cause it sounds cooler.  Heck, that's why we refer to a certain archive filetype as a "tarball."

Comment: I would like to join the choir of wonderers where on Earth *distribution* is pronounced as "distrobution". Or where on Mars, for that matter.

Comment: @RegDwigнt The American South has generated plenty of mal-pronunciations of this sort.  It wouldn't be a far cry to imagine a *distro*-bution.  As for where on Mars, it is typically just to the left of that big boulder, just over the hill.

Comment: @DavidM last I checked, the American South was in charge of oil, cows, and meth, but not Linux distributions. Like, *at all*.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I'm from and currently in the American South and I can attest to the fact that many people say distrobution down here. And there are plenty of folks in charge of "oll" fields, but they might laugh if you say "oil".

Comment: @RegDwigнt You merely asked *where on Earth distribution is pronounced as "distribution".*  You didn't ask from where are Linux distributions sourced.  ;-)

Comment: Shortening Distribution to Distri sounds like a prefix, so they needed another letter.  Replacing I with O sounded the best.

Comment: I have always wondered a similar thing, why is "combination" shortened to "combo".

Comment: Same reason. Combi sounds like a contraction.

Comment: _Distro_ is also used in electrical installation (at least in the theatre world, which is the only part I have direct knowledge of).

Comment: For every Roman or Slavic, distri is plural. Distro is singular.

Comment: The second "i" in distribution is unstressed. Which in this case causes it to be reduced to a schwa ("uh") sound. It would most likely retain the schwa sound if we replaced (misspelled) it with an "a","o", or "u" (So you might make an argument for any of them). Now if we were to pronounce "distri", I think most people would tend to use a "long e" sound (as in eat). That sounds significantly different. Of the remaining vowel choices,  The o ending seems much more similar to other English words. The others just sound foreign.

Comment: @ChrisH Some areas of the UK (Such as some parts of the south coast) do pronounce it as if there were an o, I think this is more of a regional accent variation than a national one.

Comment: @Vality, that's interesting, I've obviously heard a schwa as Tim Seguine says, but never the clear "o" of *distro*.

Comment: Interestingly (wikipedia says)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distro] that *distro* may also refer to a zine distributor, could there be some adoption from zine culture into early open source. (I say citation needed to wp)

Comment: @TylerH, As another born-and-raised southerner who has only been north of the Mason-Dixon line for at most 2 weeks at a time, I must say I've never heard anyone say "distrobution" (although I've certainly heard "oll fields"). If it is a regional thing, is must be even more localized that "the American south." I'm currently in Texas, and lived in Virginia for many years.

Comment: @BrianS Possibly more localized; I am from Georgia. AFAIK we sound pretty different from Texans.

Comment: Actually, I would have expected a pure truncation to yield `dist` rather than `distri`...

Comment: I'm from the UK and I'd pronounce it neither distribution nor distrobution but more like distrabution.

Comment: Why not leave the last vowel off altogether for "dist"?

Comment: @DanD. What? Distri would still be said.. "distrih," as it is said in "distrihbewshun" (forgive my lazy phonetics).

Comment: I'm from the UK and my department is called Distribution. We pronounce the second i the same as the first so "Dis-tri-byu-shun". So the 'trib' is the same sound as in 'tribble'.

Comment: maybe [this](http://lexis.univ-lyon3.fr/IMG/pdf/Lexis_special_1_Jamet.pdf) is an interesting read. It suggests that it's origin could be traced to French, where it's common to clip to an open vowel and, more specifically, in 'o'. My second language is French and I tend to agree, but it's certainly not hard proof and so a comment and by no means an answer.

Comment: "Distro" is more cool than "Distri" :P

Answer (score 75, accepted):

My guess is that *distro* might have been inspired by shortenings like *repo[sitory]*, *algo[rithm]*, *memo[randum]* &c.

Comment: This is the only correct answer given so far. Deriving slang- or jargon-like words with _-o_ is a somewhat productive possibility in English (non-technical ones include ‘weirdo’, ‘psycho’, ‘sicko’, ‘hobbo’, etc.). Using _-y/-ie/-ee_ is also a possibility (‘yuppie’, ‘yankee’, ‘hippie’, ‘indie’), but _-o_ is more commonly used when deriving technical terms. The derivational vowel does not have to be part of the base, though it can be.

Comment: Actually, 'Yankee' is 17th century Dutch. The story I've heard is that the Dutch colonists in New Amsterdam dismissed the encroaching English settlers (Connecticut and eastern Long Island) as "John Cheese" (Jan Kees, "Yon Keez"), which became Anglicized to "Yankees".

Comment: More correctly, Yankee is **about** 17th Century Dutch, not from their language.

Comment: How does this explain combination -> combo as wondered by @Michael? or India -> Indo-

Comment: @user13107 because *combo* is slang. *Indo-* is a separate issue unrelated to this question.

Comment: @Oldcat -- to be precise, it was used **by** the Dutch **about** the English.

Comment: @PhilPerry I doubt that. `Jan` and `Kees` were (and still are) very common Dutch first names. It's very likely that many of the Dutch settlers in New Amsterdam (later New York) were in fact called `Jan` or `Kees`. That makes it much more likely that the word was used by the **English** about the **Dutch**.

Comment: I had assumed it arose in the same way that ["convo"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/convo) came to mean "conversation"

Comment: Ditto beano, bingo (name-o), wino, kiddo, psycho, etc. Some of these will be derived from the Greek root form (-o), and some from the English whimsical -oh. There may also be influence from Italian/Spanish endings, but it's obviously a very productive suffix in English.

Answer (score 57):

Due to the Latin influence, "-o" is a much more natural-sounding ending for a singular noun in English than "-i".  My best guess is that this subconsciously affected the coinage.

Comment: I honestly think this is most correct.  Directly chopping off the end of "distribution" to get "dis-trih" doesn't sound natural at all, and attempting to pluralize it as "dis-trihs" is even worse.  Using an 'o' is the next closest vowel that doesn't sound bad.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker but "-i" would sound like a plural from Latin "distus" just borrowed directly from there.

Comment: @Izkata - Agreed. Similarly, I've heard "presentation" abbreviated to "preso", though that's one case where even the "o" sounds somewhat unnatural to my ear.

Comment: Maybe less directly Latin than Spanish, Italian and French, maybe even Portuguese.

In all of those languages, given the popularity of Latin '-tio' constructions, an o is the last thing you hear in a fancy word,  (though it may be nasalized.)

And most of their neologisms end that way.

Comment: @user7626 -- We would go with Prezzy, no?  That kind of holds up a Latin influence (direct or indirect) because the other big class of latin words are in e/i and end with that'y' sound.

Answer (score 32):

The OE has [an extensive entry on the -o suffix](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/129455) ($) which I excerpt here:

> The shortening of a word immediately after a medial o , and in
>   particular where this occurs at the end of a prefix or combining form,
>   first appears in the late 17th cent. and early 18th centuries, e.g.
>   plenipo n., memo n., and hypo n.1 **This probably established an
>   association of the ending -o with casual or light-hearted use which it
>   has retained ever since.** Further examples are attested in the early
>   19th cent., e.g. (combining forms) Anglo n.1, mezzo n.1, typo n.;
>   (other words) compo n.2, loco n.1 After 1851 this type of clipping
>   becomes, and has remained, extremely common.

Comment: +1. See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78292/what-purpose-does-an-o-serve

Answer (score 27):

The pronunciation of "distribution" is:

> [dis·tri·bu·tion](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/distribution) — [dis-truh-byoo-shuhn] — /ˌdɪstrəˈbyuʃən/

"-stri" would typically be pronounced similar to the beginning of "street" or "stripe".

"-stro", on the other hand, would be pronounced similar to the beginning of "strobe" which isn't exactly the same but close enough in American English that we'd rather say "distro" than "distri".

Furthermore, the "-tri" ending is [very rare in English](http://www.scrabblefinder.com/ends-with/tri/) with "-tro" being [slightly more common](http://www.scrabblefinder.com/ends-with/tro/).

Comment: It's the same sound as in *vegetable*, and we shorten that to *veggie*.

Comment: We also shorten vegetable to "veg". What's your point?

Comment: That the shortening of a word at a schwa to *o* instead of *i* is not a given.

Comment: I have never heard anyone say “distrəbution”.

Comment: @kinokijuf: There are alternative pronunciations but this was pulled straight from the dictionary. Something I have personally heard is the "o" from "distro" getting pushed back into "distribution" to sound like "distrobution." *shrug*

Comment: @kinokijuf: It sounds like you are either sheltered or don't know the range of sounds that are denoted by schwa.

Comment: @MattЭллен: I'm not completely sure which sound in *vegetable* Peter was referring to. If we're breaking at schwas, then the potential shortening under consideration seems to be *vegeto* (with a possible two-syllable pronunciation somewhat like vej-toe). Most AmE speakers I've heard don't pronounce the second 'e' in *vegetable* at all (indeed this is the leading pronunciation listed in my dictionary); the more stilted or "proper-sounding" 4-syllable pronunciation has the 2nd syllable stressed just enough to be listed as a short 'i' in my dead-tree *American Heritage Dictionary*.

Comment: @PeterShor and MattЭллен: I fully acknowledge that some (maybe most today, I don't know) dictionaries do list the second 'e' in the 4-syllable *vegetable* pronunciation as a schwa.

Comment: @John Y: And the *Oxford Dictionaries Online* says that [both](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/distribution?q=distribution) of those sounds are short 'i's in British English (which is the pronunciation that I use, despite being American, and assuming I pronounce the second syllable of vegetable, which I usually don't).

Answer (score 12):

If you create a new word, similarity to already existing words makes the difference between "sound good" and "sound weird".

"Distro" is very similar to already existing word "bistro". There are also "maestro", "electro", "nitro", "metro", "retro" etc.

On the other hand, I don't know any word with singular ending with "-tri". It looks like some plural form (like "uteri").

Comment: *Pantry*? *Pastry*?

Comment: @PeterShor but this is -try, not -tri

Comment: _Petri_ (as in dish), but I can't finds any more off the top of my head.

Comment: Maestro can be pluralized (as per the Italian way) as maestri.

Comment: @РСТȢѸФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ Whether a word-final /i/ is spelt _-y_ (as in _puppy_) or _-i_ (as in _petri_) doesn’t matter one iota. It could be spelt _-ie_ (as in _doggie_), _-ey_ (as in _bogey_), _-ieu_ (as in _beaulieu_), _-iz_ (as in _Agassiz_), or _-ough_ (as in _Colcolough_) for all the difference it would make. There are plenty of other words that would be good parallels for a shortened _distribution_ with a final /i/, not least Peter’s _pastry_. If that had been the vowel adopted, it would almost certainly have ended up being spelt a _distry_ or a _distrie_, though.

Answer (score 1):

In Germany, 'distri' is short for distributor (i.e. a person or company that distributes wares to retailers). So I always assumed that that was there first, and to avoid ambiguity, 'distro' was chosen for the noun 'distribution'.

Comment: I don't believe this has any chance of being the definitive answer to the question, but to me it's yet another factor that supports the popular use of *distro* and works against *distri* as a contender.

Comment: I'm German and I've never heard the abbreviation "Distri" for "Distributor" while I frequently encounter "Distri" as a shortening of "Distribution" in the context of Linux distributions.

Comment: @Christian, interesting. Just as an additional data point: Are you in any way involved in retail or creating physical goods that need a distributor?

Comment: Nope, not personally.

Comment: We do at work, so I suppose it could be considered technical jargon then. I never really thought about whether "normal" people would understand this word. But then, when I first heard it, it was obvious from context.

Answer (score 1):

An abbreviation doesn't have to use an unbroken sequence of letters beginning with the start of the word, so "DISTRibutiOn" can collapse to "distro".

What does "Linux" itself stand for if not "LINUs' (variant of) uniX"?

At the risk of triggering Godwin's Law, there is the rather (in)famous example of "NAtionalsoZIalistische".

Comment: Wiktionary points out that ["Nazi"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Nazi) is just the first two syllables of "Nationalsozialistische."

Answer (score 0):

Uh, because *distro* sounds awesome...

*Distri* sounds like a New Yorker pointing out which bit of flora you want *duh gahdnuh (gardener) to cut down.*  [*Dis tree* . . . as opposed to *dat tree*.]

And before anyone complains that is a Boston accent: Gawdnuh is Boston.  Gahdnuh is New York.  I'll let @RegDwigнt translate that into IPA for anyone who wishes.  ;-)

Comment: @RegDwigнt ... See above

Comment: Wouldn't a GnuYawkah pronounce "the gardener" as "deh gahdnuh". To my eye "de" would be pronounced with a long "e" (e.g. "dee") which I don't believe would be the common GnuYawkese pronunciation. YMMV. (And IANAGY).

Comment: @BobJarvis Duh or Deh depending upon where you were from, I'd say.   I'll edit it.

Answer (score -1):

Because the i in "distri" would be short, and awkward.

In English when you have a vowel sound followed by a consonant, the syllable break is generally between them for long vowels, and after them for short vowels.

Consider: pro/nounce or ma/king, vs. pub/lic or but/ton.

Consequently, we don't really have dangling short vowels very often - at the end of words or anywhere else.

Comment: The i in _making_ is short, which basically invalidates your point completely. Another thing that does so is that English has plenty of dangling short vowels. All the words in _-(l)y_ or _-ie_ would basically be exact parallels to _distro_ with a final /i/, not to mention the even more perfect parallel mentioned in Peter’s comment to PCT[etc.]’s answer: _pastry_. There is nothing whatsoever wrong or unnatural about dangling short vowels in English.

Answer (score -2):

For precisely the same reason that "duplication" gets abbreved as "dupe", as in someone gullible or easily fooled.  The answer is, "because".

Comment: Not the most helpful answer in the world as it is phrased.  Instead of because you might have said, by convention.

Comment: Perhaps you are unaware of "[just] because" being used to convey "no real reason"?

Answer (score -3):

*Distro* is slang. One usage example is http://distrowatch.com. And if you google for *distribution etymology*, you get the following diagram.

Latin: distribuere -> distributio

English: distribute -> distribution

If you pronounce *distribution* in English, it sounds like *distribjuschen* (http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/pronunciation/business-english/distribution).

But Linux and many open source distributions come from Europe. And this term could have been coined in Germany where distribution is pronounced differently
(http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Distribution, no voice recording).

In the English *distribution*, only the first two syllables are strong (*distri*); the *bution* follows after like a tail. But in the German *distribution*, the *dis* is strong, the *tri* is fairly weak, the *bu* is strong and the *tion* again is strong: *DIStriBUtiON* vs *DISTRIbution*.

So from the English pronunciation, going to *distri* is most logical. In German however the *tri* is weak so going to *distri* makes no phonetic sense.

Comment: No. In English,the first and third syllables are strong.

Comment: Did _distro_ originate with Linux? If so, could Torvald's native Finnish (Suomi?) have had some influence on the term?

Comment: Not really clear @PhilPerry https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=7&case_insensitive=on&content=distro&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cdistro%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdistro%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDistro%3B%2Cc0 does not point out where but only when the term came into use

Comment: @PhilPerry, Linus is not a native Finnish speaker. He's Finnish, but he's part of the small Swedish-speaking minority.

Comment: @tobyink Though that minority is large enough to make Swedish one of the national languages in Finland http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_of_Finland #funfact

Comment: He also only wrote the kernel which is as far from a Linux *distribution* as you can get ;)