# What is a doco?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Source: [Running Linux, 5th Edition by Matthias Kalle Dalheimer and Matt Welsh (2006)](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007607.do)

Example:

> We would also like to thank the following people for their work on the Linux operat-
>   ing system—without all of them, there wouldn’t be anything to write a book about:
>   Linus Torvalds, Richard Stallman, Donald Becker, Alan Cox, Remy Card, Eric Ray-
>   mond, Ted T’so, H. J. Lu, Miguel de Icaza, Ross Biro, Drew Eckhardt, Ed Carp, Eric
>   Youngdale, Fred van Kempen, Steven Tweedie, Patrick Volkerding, Dirk Hohndel,
>   Matthias Ettrich, and all of the other hackers, from the kernel grunts to the lowly
>   **docos**, too numerous to mention here.

What does this word mean?

Comment: People who write technical documentation, I believe...

Comment: Yeah, 40 years in the industry and I don't recall ever hearing/seeing it, but in that context I would assume it to be short for "documentation writer", et al (and a bit pejorative, to boot).

Comment: Just for posterior:  In my corner of the world these people (even the women) were known as "the pubs guys".

Comment: _Doco_ appears to be yet another entry in the family of word shortenings that truncate a multisyllable word to its first syllable and then add an -o suffix ending, as with _ammo_, _convo_, _distro_, _limo_, and _provo_. For further discussion of this phenomenon, see [Why is "ammunition" shortened to "ammo" and not "ammu"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/249811/why-is-ammunition-shortened-to-ammo-and-not-ammu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Doco* seems to be a word looking for legitimization.

The word in the question context would mean ‘documentation writer’. The word has not yet established a general or usual meaning in English. This is how [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/doco) defines the relevant meaning:

> **Doco** *noun, jargon*
>
> 1. (In-house jargon at Symbolics) A documentation writer.
>      See also [devo](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/devo) and [mango](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mango).
> 2. (UK) A short technical document. A "doco" is often not the documentation passed to management.
>      Compare [doc](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/doc).