# "Jesus is a coming" - what's the exact grammatical role of the "a" before the gerund?

Tags: slang, gerunds, indefinite-articles, morphology, lyrics

I've noticed that in the common use of English, namely in songs, there is also an extra redundant(?) "*a*" before a *gerund*, such as in a gospel song I heard

> Jesus is *a* coming

(this particular phrase looks like [quoted here](http://songmeanings.com/songs/view/3530822107859441126/)).

What's the *exact grammatical role* of this extra inserted *a*? Is it the *indefinite article*? Why is it there? Is there any specific reason for it, or is it just bad language, slang or what? Has it developed from a pause in the speech when the speaker needed an extra time to find the word? Something like this:

> Jesus is a... what the hell is he.. well, coming!

ADDED:

Based on a comment I am supposed to spell it as

> Jesus is *a*-coming

so maybe you may comment on this, too.

Comment: Correct your spelling. Jesus is *a-coming,* where *a-coming* is the verb. It's not the article *a*. This used to have a grammatical meaning. In the dialects where it is still used, I don't know whether it still has a grammatical meaning (distinguishing it from *Jesus is coming*), or whether it's just a holdover.

Comment: @Peter: Please create it as an answer. That's exactly what I am asking *about* - the grammatical role of the *a*. So if your answer is "it's a part of the verb", please be more specific!

Comment: I suspect that [What purpose does an -o serve?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78292/what-purpose-does-an-o-serve) is related, although *Sumer is icumen in* has a similar construction.

Comment: The question http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45886/what-is-the-story-behind-a-prefix-suffix which this was marked as a duplicate does not have an accepted answer :)

Comment: @Honza Zidek: I can't help it if the previous poster didn't bother to accept any of the answers. The [one from Robusto](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/56380/2637) covers the matter perfectly well, IMHO.