# Adding the letter O onto the end of root words like - friendo, fatso, f*cko, weirdo, etc

Tags: meaning, slang, connotation, suffixes

I have seen these type of words both in movies and on the net. Now, I am trying to understand, what is the point in adding the letter O onto the end of root words? Does it act as a intensifier of the negative meaning of a root word (in case a root word per se has a negative connotation)? If so, then what happens if a root has a neutral or positive connotation? What would be the meaning then?

Comment: And the Aussies do it all the time: journalist, journo. It does not seem to connote negatively for them. In AmE, it can be negative or positive. One positive one is "no problemo", which I personally cannot stand. :)

Comment: @Lambie understando!

Comment: Related: [What purpose does an -o serve?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/78292/8019)

Comment: Here is a list of Aussie words: https://www.australiablog.com/culture/favorite-australian-slang-add-an-o.html

Comment: I'm absolutely certain that *no problemo* came to us (where I live) from Spanish language influence. Not sure about the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Michael Quinion, *Ologies and Isms: Word Beginning and Endings* has an interesting suggestion regarding the origin of *-o* as an attachment to freestanding nouns or adjectives:

> **-o** *Marking informally shortened or slang nouns.* {Perhaps from the interjection *oh!*, or the use of *-o* in ballads to terminate lines; its use has been reinforced by shortened forms ending in the linking vowel -o-}
>
> Though a wide variety of nouns in English end in **-o**, this suffix occurs only in words that have been formed from other native words in one of two specific ways. One method is to informally abbreviate a longer term, of which a few examples out of many are ***ammo***, ***condo***, ***hippo***, ***limo***, and ***photo***.Others are based on an adjective or noun, to which the suffix is added to create a colloquial or slangy terms, which is often but by no means always derogatory: **beano** (from *beanfeast*), **boyo**, **cheapo**, **pervo** (from *pervert*), **pinko**, **righto**, **sicko**, **weirdo**, **wino**.

The attachment of *-o* endings in ballads goes back centuries, as for example in the ballad "[The Bonnie Lass o' Fyvie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bonnie_Lass_o%27_Fyvie)," which in one version attaches *-o* to  no fewer than sixteen normal English words, as well as to the proper names *Fyvie* and *Peggy*. All of these *-o* words fall at the ends of lines (in fact at the end of the second and fourth lines of each of the ballad's quatrains) corroborating the notion that *-o* plays a line-terminating role in at least some ballads. Nevertheless, citing that use of *-o* endings as the source of current *-o* words, even if it is correct (which is not beyond question), doesn't explain why people chose *-o* for that purpose way back then. It basically just kicks the can a few centuries down the road.

As Quinion observes, wordos are inherently slangy and often have negative connotations. But in the examples that Quinion lists, some *-o* words aren't negative, and some that are negative are informal alterations of words that are themselves negative (*cheap*, *sick*, *weird*—to which we can add *dumb*, *creep*, *lame*, *stink*, and so on). To my mind, the crucial function of *-o* in modern usage isn't to render a neutral word negative; it's to slangify and informalize a staid, sober, reputable word—often in tandem with converting the word from an adjective into a noun.

Answer (score 1):

**Slang Words Ending in “O”** [Daily Writings](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/slang-words-ending-in-o/)

These have been around for a long time.  Some actually make it into the registries: condo & cheerio. In slang use they call attention to the base meaning of the word: f**ko doggo beardo and the list goes on. One frequent U. S. use is 'wrongo -dude!'

Interesting example:

> There used to be a famous cigarette lighter named “Zippo”. There was
>   also a Japanese bomber code named “Betty”. Betty would catch fire
>   easily when hit by allied fire. The Yanks took to calling them zippos,
>   and even the Japanese crewmen called these planes the same.

And more from the Aussies:  [Aussie Slang](https://www.australiablog.com/culture/favorite-australian-slang-add-an-o.html)

Comment: Ah shucks. Where are our Aussie friends? If I were younger, I would go to Australia or New Zealand and never come back. :)

Comment: @Lambie with your permission adding aussie blog link

Answer (score 1):

The *OED* attributes use of this slang *-o* suffix to three factors.

> the final syllable of words of chiefly Romance origin

Think **bongo**, **mango**, and **calico**.

> the vowel that became final after the shortening of a word by dropping the syllables following a medial o , especially in compounds truncated after a prefix or combining form ending in *-o*

In this case, think of slang words cut short after a medial o, like using the word **psycho** instead of **psychopath**.

> **ho** *int.1*, **O** *int.*, and **oh** *int.*, occurring as a second element in various exclamatory phrases. The suffix is attached both to full words and to truncated forms of words and phrases.

Here the *OED* is referring to derivatives of words followed by *Ho!* like **Righto**, which derives from **Right ho**.

Answer (score -1):

Weirdo is just the slang abbreviation for someone who is being weird. That's what adding the letter O is for.

Comment: Then why add the O to friend? Friend already represents a person who is, well, a friend, how do you explain the added o?